# Greenplum : Object Creation Date

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I have used pg_stat_operations to know when a table or view is created or altered,

I want to know when a function or sequence is created or modified.
(Function list is availed at pg_proc and information_schema.routines but there is no option for creation or modification date)

Is there any way to find it out???

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't keep track of object creation timestamps. Unless Greenplum added them, there's no such facility.

Comment: The only option is to grep through pg_log